# Display specific products on a CMS page

Tags: magento, content-management-system, product

Could someone help me with some code to display specific products on a Magento CMS page?
The idea being that I build a page that has multiple sections on it (sections meaning a heading, some intro text and a small handful of products) and the user can add a selection of the displayed products to their cart from this page.

Ideally, the products should be displayed in the grid format, and I should be able to display between 1 and 6 products in each section.

I am using Magento 1.4.0.1 currently.

Cheers!

Comment: You're more likely to get considered responses if you accept answers on some of your previous questions, just so you're aware.

Comment: Thanks Joseph - I hadn't realised - comment appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a CMS Widget to do this for you.

Here is one: [Product List Widget](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/4014/category_listing_widget)
It isn't free but there are others if you look around.